# Seeing a Hashed Password

Tags: linux

Is there a linux command to see the hashed password? Not the actual password but just the hash over it. I have tried showing hash table and such but that has yet to work. Feel like I'm just missing a simple command.

Comment: `sudo cat /etc/shadow`

Comment: I tried the sudo command and it didn't work. I'm just looking for a trace of a hash on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix/Linux systems the hashed passwords of all users are stored into the file `/etc/shadow` and - for security reasons - this is readable only to `root`.
Therefore there is no way for an unprivileged user to read its contents.

However, if the [NIS service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) is enabled in your system/network, you can see the hashed passwords in the second column of the output of the command `ypcat passwd`.